How to resolve Error: Definition for rule 'tailwindcss/classname-order' was not found
My Next[15.0.3] app is failing to commit due to the error: 1:1  Error: Definition for rule 'tailwindcss/classname-order' was not found.  tailwindcss/classname-order
I'm unable to find any current rule definitions in the project.
package.json:
{
  "name": "next-template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "format:check": "prettier --check .",
    "prepare": "husky",
    "lint:fix": "next lint --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "15.0.3",
    "react": "19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106",
    "react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^19.6.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^19.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.16.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^3.17.5",
    "husky": "^9.1.7",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.10",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "3.4.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.6.9",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

.eslintrc.json
{
  "extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "next/typescript",
    "plugin:tailwindcss/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": ["error", { "allow": ["info", "warn", "error"] }],
    "tailwindcss/classname-order": "warn",
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
    "@next/next/no-page-custom-font": "off"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "tailwindcss": {
      "callees": ["classnames", "clsx", "ctl"],
      "config": "tailwind.config.ts",
      "cssFiles": [
        "**/*.css",
        "!**/node_modules",
        "!**/.*",
        "!**/dist",
        "!**/build"
      ],
      "cssFilesRefreshRate": "5_000",
      "removeDuplicates": true,
      "skipClassAttribute": false,
      "classRegex": "^class(Name)?$"
    }
  }
}

